# How to dynamically change the x-axis in ApexCharts to dates?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, date, apexcharts

How do I dynamically change the max value of the x-axis to today's date? and the min value up to 15 weeks ago? How can change the x-axis to dynamically do this?

```
chart:{
    animations:{
        enabled: false,
    },
    toolbar: {
        show: false,
    },
    height:450,
    width: '100%',
    type: 'bar',
    background:'#ffffff',
    forColor: '#333'
},
series:[{
    name:'Calories',
    data:[80,81,83,85,82,89,90]
        }],
dataLabels:{
    enabled:false
},
markers: {
    size:0,
},
xaxis:{
    type: 'datetime',
      categories: [
         sevenWeeksBack,date
      ],
    // datetimeUTC:true,
    // datetimeFormatter:{
    //     year: 'yyyy',
    //     month:"Mmm",
    //     day: "dd"
    // },
    //   labels:{
    //       show:true,
    //   },
    //min: new Date(sevenWeeksBack).getTime(),
     //max: new Date().getTime(),
     //range: new Date(sevenWeeksBack).getTime(),
    // min:new Date(Date.now()-604800000),
     // tickAmount: 'dataPoints' 
},
yaxis:[{
        title:{
            text: ''
        }
}],
plotOptions:{
    bar:{
    horizontal: false
    }
},
fill:{
    colors: ['#33e400']
},
title:{
    text: 'Food Calories',
    align: 'left',
    margin: 20,
    offsetY: 20,
    style:{
        fontSize: '25px'
    }
},
tooltip: {
    enabled:false,
    x: {
        format: 'dd MMM yyyy'
      }
  },
  states: {
    hover: {
        filter: {
            type: 'none',
        }
    }
}
```

};

The incoming data will contain up to 90 days of worth of data (90 values).
How can I display the x-axis to do dates?

This chart is intended to display up to 90 days. I have tried using momentjs to dynamically change the max and min value but with no success

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't mix `type: 'datetime'` with `categories`, if you're using `categories` you're probably better off using `type: 'category'`. That said, I believe there are two approaches you can take:

1. If you've already formatted your dates and put them into the categories array *and* you know you'll always be receiving 90 days worth of values - then it'll format as you expect. There's a nice example of that approach [here](https://codepen.io/apexcharts/pen/PQpaLb), referred to in the [docs](https://apexcharts.com/docs/series/) under "1). Single values". (This approach isn't working for you currently because from what I can see you only have 7 values in your `series.data`.)
2. Use `type: 'datetime'` and drop the categories. This will allow you to format using `x.min` and `x.max` as you've tried. Caveat here is that you'll need to include the timestamp with each data point when passing to ApexCharts, so you might have to do some pre-processing. This is referred to as "3). Timeline Series" in the [docs](https://apexcharts.com/docs/series/). I put together a [codepen](https://codepen.io/schafo/pen/PoZLMEp) showing this approach, using both of the two timeline series formats.

Comment: Hi Oscar, Thanks for shedding some light on the issue, a lot of the doubts I had regards implementation, have been clarified. In regards to the data being displayed. I have an incoming array that can hold UP to 90 days worth of data (i.e Calories burned for each day in the last 90 days). Since a lot of this " to be displayed information" is user input I cannot guarantee 90 datapoints but at most 90 and at least 0. What would be the way to go about this? The incoming array updates on daily basis. As of now, I am using an array holding the last 13 weeks since today and updates every day. Thanks!

Comment: Without deviating to much from the original question - the `'datetime'` approach sounds like it's more suited. You'll need to figure out a way to handle those data points, before passing them to ApexCharts, and knowing which data point corresponds to which date. Slightly off topic - but maybe an [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) would be a better approach than an array, or find a way to pad the array? But I'll leave that for you to decide.

Comment: This allows you to gain much better control over the width of the bars too, as you are dealing with a known set of intervals along the axis.